# Factor importance in multivariate experiment

Tags: anova, multivariate-analysis, experiment-design

I'm trying to analyze a multivariate experiment and show impact of each factor in a multivariate experiment. The general way to do this analysis would be to perform ANOVA:

```r
library(car)
model <- lm(breaks ~ wool + tension, data = warpbreaks)
Anova(model, type = 3)
```

which gives the following output:

```
Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: breaks
             Sum Sq Df  F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept) 20827.0  1 154.3226 < 2.2e-16 ***
wool          450.7  1   3.3393  0.073614 .  
tension      2034.3  2   7.5367  0.001378 ** 
Residuals    6747.9 50                       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

and then whenever there is significant main effect, I would continue with post-hoc comparison tests to understand what **levels** of for example tension factor are improving the dependent variable, and what levels aren't.

However, how would I go about calculating/reporting on **factor** impact? Ideally:

1. this would be a directional value that is comparable between factors (i.e. a larger number of one factor means it is more impactful and one should focus on it)
2. it would be bounded

Calculating 1-pvalue for each factor of ANOVA table is bounded, but it not directly comparable between factors (I believe).

An example of this would be Adobe Target "Influence" of a factor [image: Adobe Target "Influence" of a factor] or Visual Website Optimizer's "Impact" [image: VWO]

- What are the standard ways of doing this?
- How does that differ if my dependent variable follows non-normal (e.g. Binomial) distribution and the model has to be fit with GLM (e.g. `glm(..., family=binomial())`)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the relative impact of each variable, I don't think that there is an agreed on way to do that in linear methods like ANOVA and regression (its an important issue with me so I looked for ways to do this in the context of regression including speaking to experts).

I think the closest thing to this in regression are standardized slopes (aka beta weights). I have not run across these in ANOVA but since regression where they do exist is effectively the same method as ANOVA I am sure they exist. Note that some think these standardized slopes are not valid with dummy variables that can take on only two levels.

Comment: I added two examples of this in my question: Adobe Target and VWO. Please have a look

Comment: I think Eta squared might be what I was looking for. https://www.uccs.edu/lbecker/glm_effectsize#Eta%20squared%20(h2)